# Constructing a script using a 3rd party library

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I have started to use a Raspberry Pi 4 with Python. The project I'm working on has led me to a published Python library on GitHub ([keshavdv/victron-ble](https://github.com/keshavdv/victron-ble)).

Having installed the library, I can successfully run from the CLI (discover, read, dump). However, trying to achieve the same through a Python script has left me head scratching.

CLI commands used:

```
victron-ble discover
victron-ble dump "b5:55:aa:4d:99:33"
victron-ble read "b5:55:aa:4d:99:33"@"eb8c557386614231dbd741db97e457c5"
```

This is the code that I have tried to use:

```
from victron_ble.cli import discover
from victron_ble.cli import dump
from victron_ble.cli import read

my_id = b'b5:55:aa:4d:99:33'
#where my_id is the MAC address of the device I wish to observe

my_key = 'eb8c557386614231dbd741db97e457c5'
#where my_key is the encypytion key of the device I wish to observe

dump_result = dump(my_key)
print(dump_result)

discover_result = discover()
print(discover_result)
```

Have tried the following format of the my_id variable in hope:

```
b'b5:55:aa:4d:99:33'
'b5:55:aa:4d:99:33'
'b555aa4d9933'
b'b5-55-aa-4d-99-33'
[b5:55:aa:4d:99:33]
```

One question would be, how would I replicate the CL instruction but with the script, in particular the format required for the MAC address and key. Thank you

Comment: And ...? What's wrong with the code you wrote? See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: The code doesn’t work, throws errors

Comment: Please [edit] to include the actual traceback (as text, not as pictures, video, or a cobblestone monument). Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @IronDad75 could it be that you have the order wrong? On CLI you discover first

Answer (score 1):

So following the library script alongside the your answer script, I have amended to try and achieve the read function:

```
@cli.command(help="Read data from specified devices")
@click.argument("device_keys", nargs=-1, type=DeviceKeyParam())
def read(device_keys: List[Tuple[str, str]]):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def scan(keys):
        scanner = Scanner(keys)
        await scanner.start()

    asyncio.ensure_future(scan({k: v for k, v in device_keys}))
    loop.run_forever()
```

Using this script:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from typing import List, Tuple

from victron_ble.scanner import Scanner


def my_scan(device_keys: List[Tuple[str, str]]):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def scan(keys):
        scanner = Scanner(keys)
        await scanner.start()

    asyncio.ensure_future(scan({k: v for k, v in device_keys}))
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_id = ("b5:55:aa:4d:99:33","149c3c2865054b71962dcb06866524a9")
    logger = logging.getLogger("victron_ble")
    logging.basicConfig()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    my_scan(my_id)
```

Using the the value for my_id as above, returns error:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(scan({k: v for k, v in device_keys}))
                                     ^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If however, I amend the value of my_id to this:

```
my_id = ("b5:55:aa:4d:99:33@149c3c2865054b71962dcb06866524a9")
```

returns error:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(scan({k: v for k, v in device_keys}))
                                     ^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The CLi argument to run that returns the correct result would be:

```
victron-ble read "b5:55:aa:4d:99:33"@"149c3c2865054b71962dcb06866524a9"
```

I'm guessing is a problem with my syntax within the script??

Comment: It looks like it is expecting the value of `device_keys` being passed to your `my_scan` function to be of type `List[Tuple[str, str]])`. So I'm assuming you are missing the square brackets in your first attempt. e.g. `my_id = [("b5:55:aa:4d:99:33","149c3c2865054b71962dcb06866524a9")]` is what I would expect to work.

Comment: Simple as that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I run with the code/script that you have posted I get the following error:

```
$ python3 with_cli_funcs.py 

Usage: with_cli_funcs.py [OPTIONS] ID
Try 'with_cli_funcs.py --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (b 8 c 5 5 7 3 8 6 6 1 4 2 3 1 d b d 7 4 1 d b 9 7 e 4 5 7 c 5)

Process finished with exit code 2
```

This looks to me like the `click` library is expecting to inject the value in to the `dump` function with the decorators. https://github.com/keshavdv/victron-ble/blob/e28c5f8cc5f9f3062a2f36c2115d38214c07e741/victron_ble/cli.py#L45-L55

```py
@cli.command(help="Dump all advertisements matching the given device ID")
@click.argument("id", type=str)
def dump(id: str):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


    async def scan():
        scanner = DebugScanner(id)
        await scanner.start()


    asyncio.ensure_future(scan())
    loop.run_forever()
```

I don't have any appropriate devices so I can't test this, but it would seem like the following should work:

```py
import asyncio
import logging

from victron_ble.scanner import DebugScanner


def my_scan(id: str):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def scan():
        scanner = DebugScanner(id)
        await scanner.start()

    asyncio.ensure_future(scan())
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_id = 'b5:55:aa:4d:99:33'
    logger = logging.getLogger("victron_ble")
    logging.basicConfig()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    my_scan(my_id)
```

Comment: Hi @ukBaz, thanks for your reply to this and help with this, that worked a dream! I have tried to replicate your script to implement the Scanner (read) function. I'm still getting to grips with how to post here so will try and post my script and error I'm getting.

Comment: I'll post as an answer to my own question to try and layout the detail clearly....